# which one is a better translation and seems natural in Chinese?

Tags: translation

For the translation of the sentence:

```
Let's all press "commit" button!
```

I have three options:

- **让我们按下"Commit!"按钮**
- **我们都按''Commit!''按钮**
- **我们所有人都来按''commit遵守''按钮！**

Which is better?

Comment: What is the '"commit" button'? Some button in a computer software that you want people to press with mouse pointer? To choose one from your options, I'll go 1. Although I would say 大家一起按commit按钮 sounds better. And you know in this case commit doesn't translate to 遵守 right?

Comment: @jf328 yes, I want to use `commit` as a proper noun in quotations in quotation marks. Meaning that I don't even want to write `commit` in Chinese alphabet and with the same pronunciation as English. I want to just right `"Commit!" as the name of a botton`

Comment: Among the three translation you provided, the first one appears to be the most natural one. 让我们按下"Commit!"按钮 However, I cannot find "commit" button on my keyboard. Um... I don't know where it is. There might be a better way to say it.

Comment: I did some search and I found it is a button that appears on the screen. I don't think Chinese people call it 按钮。I will write an answer to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean a button that appears on a screen, it is better to say "点击（click）..."

> 现在，让我们点击“Commit”。

I would rather omit "键" or "按钮" in the above sentence.

按钮 normally refers to actual buttons that you can press by hand，such as the on/off button on your TV or computer.

键 can be used when you talk about keyboards, remote control and so on.

If you are talking about an actual button, your first translation appears to be the most natural one.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a exclamation mark '!', I think it is actually

```
Let's all press "commit" button simultaneously!
```

and thus the translation in Chinese is

```
让我们一起按下“commit”按钮！
```

*键 refers to a key on the keyboard; 按钮 refers to a button (on screen).